# Pictures in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert an image for ShareLaTeX, and I don't know a whole lot about the program. I saved an image to my desktop and this is the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\oddsidemargin -.25in       % Lt Margin adj for odd pages (0 = 1`` margin    )
\evensidemargin -.25in      % Rt Margin adjustment for even pages
\topmargin -.5in            % adj top margin from 1''
\footskip .5in
\textwidth 7in              % width of printed area
\textheight 8.5in             % height of printed area

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

...

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

...

\includegraphics{bgraph.jpg}
```

and nothing comes up, I don't see anything about draft in my `\documentclass` so i don't know what to do.

Comment: JPG can only be compiled with `pdflatex` or `xelatex` and `latex`  cannot.

Comment: If you're compiling the document online using sharelatex's interface, then you need to make sure that the image is in the same file directory as the `.tex` file. You can accomplish this by uploading the file to sharelatex. Do this by clicking `+ New` on the left side of your browser when you have your project open on sharelatex.

Comment: Do I just use the file name it is saved as on my desktop?

Comment: No problem. It's all working now?

Comment: Don't forget to use a \resizebox to make sure it fits on the page.

Comment: @Adam could you make that an answer!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just did! Sorry, I forgot about this question.

Comment: @Adam Thanks (voted) was just doing a sweep over the unanswered list:-)

Comment: Don't the the paper dimensions directly: Use the `geometry` package instead.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to `\includegraphics` is to make sure that the image you want to include is in the same working directory as your `.tex` file.

Now, sharelatex gives you the ability to upload extra files to the working directory of the project that you're currently working on. This is useful if, for example, you need to add pictures to your document or you want to use a bibliography file that is saved on your computer, among other things.

In order to upload a file or image to the same directory as the `.tex` file, you need to use the `+ New` function that is visible on the left side of browser window when your current project is open on sharelatex.

---

Since compilers were also mentioned in the comments here, it might also be worth pointing out that you can change the compiler to either `pdflatex`, `latex`, or `xelatex`. (As of this posting, `pdflatex`, `latex`, and `xelatex` are the only compilers supported by sharleatex.) This can be changed in the `Settings`, which is also available from the left side of the window when you have your project open.